How to delete appProperties via Java SDK
The Google Drive V3 documentation explains how to delete public properties, but it does not call out how to delete private appProperties.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/properties#delete_custom_file_properties
The V2 -> V3 migration guide states that to remove appProperties is to use the same format as to remove properties: by setting the value to null:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/v2-to-v3-reference#method_differences_between_v2_and_v3
When I make calls to update a File's appProperties it succeeds with non-null values. When I try to use null values, there appears to be no operation performed.
Example:
Given that File "123" exists with an appProperties value of {"hello":"world"},
Map<String, String> appProperties = Map.of("hello", null);
File file = new File();
file.setAppProperties(appProperties);
File response = drive.files().update("123", file);

In this case, response.getAppProperties() yields the same value as before this operation, {"hello":"world"}.
How can I remove appProperties fields?

Although I'm not sure about your whole script, in your showing script, how about modifying drive.files().update("123", file); to drive.files().update("123", file).setFields("appProperties").execute(); or drive.files().update("123", file).setFields("*").execute();? Unfortunately, I have no information about your whole script. So, I posted this as a comment. If this comment was not useful, I apologize.

I was already using the .setFields("*") on my execution call to no avail. Also no change when running .setFields("appProperties") after the update().

Thank you for replying. About I was already using the .setFields("*") on my execution call to no avail. Also no change when running .setFields("appProperties") after the update()., I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, I couldn't confirm about execute().
